# Aquamacs doesn't run python file on C-c C-c

Tags: python, aquamacs

When I run <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> on a .py file, Aquamacs returns

> Output file descriptor of python3 is closed

On the other hand, the Python shell works just fine.

How can I fix it such that I can run Python files?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Aquamacs' default Python interpreter is pyhton.el and not python-mode.el .

Installing python-mode.el from [here](https://launchpad.net/python-mode) will do the trick.